# Cypress: testing that nothing more than asserted exists

Tags: cypress, assertion

Is it possible to test that nothing more than asserted exists? E.g. I have elements A, B and C. I'm asserting that

```
cy.get('element-a').should('exist');
cy.get('element-b').should('exist');
cy.get('element-c').should('exist');
```

Then I remove A and assert that

```
cy.get('element-a').should('not.exist');
```

But is there any way to test that no other elements e.g. D or Q, of which I might not even be aware, exist on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can get every descendent element (child, grandchild, great-grandchild, etc) using `.find('*')`.

For example,

```js
cy.visit('http://example.com');
cy.get('body')
  .find('*')
  .then(descendents => {
    return [...descendents].map(d => d.tagName)
  })
  .should('deep.eq', ['DIV', 'H1', 'P', 'P', 'A'])
```

Note the tagNames are allcaps.

But it seems doubtful that you have ONLY tags such as `element-a` in your HTML. You can apply a filter, the exact code depends on what your selectors are (tagNames, classes, ids, data-cy attributes).

You may be better off using [cypress snapshot](https://github.com/cypress-io/snapshot) or similar package listed on that page.

Comment: Thank you, looks like finding all the descendants would do the job. Of course, we don't use 'element-a' as such, it's just a simple example to explain my issue. The snaphots are worth trying.

Comment: I figured `element-a` was representative, but that's a tagName - the problem would be working with the other selector types mentioned especially class selectors which can be one of a list and data-cy selectors which have extra chars surrounding them.